# `public` access qualifier and `const`ness. `-Wuninitialized`

Tags: c++, warnings, member, access-specifier

```
class Foo
{
    public:
        const int x;
};

class Bar
{
    private:
        const int x;
};
```

Output:

```
test.cpp:10:13: warning: non-static const member ‘const int Bar::x’ in class without a constructor [-Wuninitialized]
```

Why does `Bar`produce a warning but `Foo` doesn't (obviously because of access qualifier, but what is the logic?).

Comment: Is this the whole program?

Comment: This is the complete MWE that I have compile.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With those definitions, since `Foo::x` is public, you can validly instantiate a `Foo` with something like:

```
Foo f { 0 }; // C++11
```

or

```
Foo f = { 0 };
```

You can't do that for a `Bar`.

Comment: That some unusual syntax (for me at least). Could you please provide a resource.

Comment: @aiao The first is new syntax in C++11 (often badly named [uniform initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Uniform_initialization)) and is equivalent to the second. They both, in this case, perform aggregate initialization (§8.5.1 of C++11).